# Turn off a single tmux area

Tags: tmux

So I have tmux running, with 4 windows with one in each quarter. Is there some way to turn off one quarter without another window snapping into its place? That is having a place in tmux which is not assigned to a shell instance?

Comment: Is it the "snapping into place" that is the issue, or creating an "empty" pane?

Comment: It's the "having an empty pane"

Comment: You could just run `tmux clock` in it ;-)